# Options for running k8s in local system without vm (single node)

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, microk8s

I want to use tool running k8s in single node for devlopment. But without using VM.
I could find tools using vm. But I could not find tools without vm.
Microk8s is only tool satisfing my condition.

Is there any other options?

- Not using vm
- Running k8s locally (single node)

Thank you.

Comment: `kind` ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout K3s : Lightweight Kubernetes. Easy to install, half the memory, all in a binary less than 50mb.

Refer https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/

Comment: Thank you. I choose this option in my project. It is exactly what I looking for .

Answer (score 1):

You can use kind https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind

and minikube without VM by `minikube start --vm-driver=none`